# Fix image relative to a point on a scaling background

Tags: css, position, css-float, background-image, css-position

I am trying to fix an image to a certain point in the background image for a project.
I've created a jsbin as I couldn't find the words to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.
http://jsbin.com/esUNEKIM/2/

In the example, the little map pointer is perfectly placed at the tip of the finger in the background image (at my resolution and full screen), but moves when the image scales down.

Any clues?

PS: I need the two images to be separate. I'm open to hacks as this will be a temporary landing page and we don't really care about old IE compatibility here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see it now when I shrink my browser vertically - you'll need to add in vertical media queries (e.g.: http://cognition.happycog.com/article/go-vertical/) or use JavaScript.

I actually didn't see it move when it scaled-down but when it scaled up. For me, 230px seems to work until a given point (around 1600px). Use a media-query to change the right position. It looks to me like 16% seems to work after that point.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px){
    #capsule {
    right: 16%;
    }
}
```

If you're still seeing it on scale-down, you can add multiple media-queries to adjust the position.